# Exit Emacs Calendar without having to save the diary file

Tags: calendar, diary

When I create appointments in Emacs `diary` via the `calendar`, I have to save  changes to the diary file before being able to exit the calendar. I have tried to set up Emacs to automatically save the diary file once changes have been made with this code:

```
(add-hook 'diary-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'diary-show-all-entries nil t)
            (auto-save-mode)))
```

However, hitting `q` in calendar still prompts me with these words:

```
Diary modified; do you really want to exit the calendar? (y or n)
```

This from calendar.el:

```
(defun calendar-exit (&optional kill)
  "Get out of the calendar window and hide it and related buffers."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((diary-buffer (get-file-buffer diary-file))
        (calendar-buffers (calendar-buffer-list)))
    (when (or (not diary-buffer)
              (not (buffer-modified-p diary-buffer))
              (yes-or-no-p
               "Diary modified; do you really want to exit the calendar? "))
      (if (and calendar-setup (display-multi-frame-p))
          ;; FIXME: replace this cruft with the `quit-restore' window property
          (dolist (w (window-list-1 nil nil t))
            (if (and (memq (window-buffer w) calendar-buffers)
                     (window-dedicated-p w))
                (if (eq (window-deletable-p w) 'frame)
            (if calendar-remove-frame-by-deleting
            (delete-frame (window-frame w))
              (iconify-frame (window-frame w)))
          (quit-window kill w))))
        (dolist (b calendar-buffers)
          (quit-windows-on b kill))))))
```

I would like to be able to save the diary file automatically and exit calendar without confirmation.

Comment: You can add a `before` advice to `calendar-exit` to save the diary: do  `C-h i g (elisp)Advising RET` for more information.

Comment: I get `user-error: No such node or anchor: Advising`

Comment: You can get there from the Elisp section, in Advising Functions. Or just go to the documentation on the web: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

What you're looking for is something like `(advice-add 'calendar-exit :before 'my/save-calendar-before-exit)`

Comment: Do you have the Emacs Lisp documentation installed? If you say `C-h i` do you see the Elisp manual? If not, you should install it. You could use the online docs as @BrianCully suggests, but that is no substitute for using Info in emacs itself.

Comment: I will install it and revert if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (lightly tested) implementation along the lines in the comments:

```el
(defun my/save-diary-before-calendar-exit (_)
   (let ((diary-buffer (get-file-buffer diary-file)))
        (or (not diary-buffer)
            (not (buffer-modified-p diary-buffer))
            (with-current-buffer diary-buffer (save-buffer)))))

(advice-add 'calendar-exit :before #'my/save-diary-before-calendar-exit)
```

The tests are cribbed from `calendar-exit` itself: get the buffer of the diary file and if the buffer exists and is modified, save it.

If you want to make this permanent, you need to add the code above to your init file.

And if at any point you want to remove the advice, say:

```el
(advice-remove 'calendar-exit #'my/save-diary-before-calendar-exit)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much.